# Why is making a white laser so difficult?

Tags: lasers

There are red, green, and blue lasers out there but i can't find a white laser? how hard is to make one? Is it possible?

Comment: [Cross-posted to Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415429/44126).

Answer (score 3):

Its not hard- it bends the idea of what a laser is. Lasers have a single (or very narrow) wavelength of light emitted. There is no "white" wavelength- its just what your eye perceives from a (relatively) full spectrum of wavelengths.

This is generally considered by the scientific community to be an advantage, not a disadvantage. You can do many cool things with a single wavelength that you can't do with a broad spectrum.

You could potentially make a white-ish laser by syncing up many different lasers to make a combination beam that your eye perceives as white. This would be a very difficult engineering problem though, if you actually wanted a spatially coherent laser. Thanks to OpticalResonator for pointing out [some folks who managed to do it in a single crystal](https://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2015.149), which is pretty wild.

Comment: It has actually been done in 2015, see this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2015.149

Comment: Whoa, cool! I considered that possibility but omitted it because I wasn't sure it would even count as a laser since it doesn't make any sense for it to be temporally coherent. Do they address that point in the full text (I'm stuck on the paywall)?

Comment: I‘m sadly also stuck there :P it does come from one single laser active medium, with 3 layers that emit on 3 wavelengths, so I would assume that it is coherent

Comment: *Some* lasers have a narrow frequency spectrum in their emissions; other lasers (typically used for pulsed emission) emit over extremely broad spectra that can span close to an octave. Narrow-band emission can seem like the entirety of laser science for people who work with CW lasers, but it is not the only useful mode of operation.